# Can one use mongoengine to define a document first, then use pymongo to insert many documents?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

MongoEngine is good for defining a document for data validation. Raw pymongo is lacking in this area. Can I use MongoEngine to define a document first, then use pymongo to insertMany documents into an empty collection? If yes, will pymongo's insertMany() do data validation based on the document definition set by mongoengine?

Can pymongo and mongoengine code be mixed together in the same python script?

I am using python 3.7, mongodb v4.2.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me breakdown your question into three parts.

1. Can i use mongoengine validation with pymongo ?
2. If used insertmany then how do validate ?
3. Can pymongo and mongoengine code be mixed together in the same python script?

Answers -:

1. No you cannot use mongoengine validation with pymongo. Because validation is define in mongoengine module like -:

> snap from mongoengine lib -- mongoengine -> common.py:

[image]

> So, when you use validation in mongoenine these function is called and validate the data. If you want to validate you data for pymongo, then you have to write custom validation code for that.

2. `Insertmany()` is seperate function, there is no relation with mongoengine. So mongoenine define is not worked with `Insertmany()`.
3. Yes, You can write pymongo and mongoengine code together in same python script. [In some scenario we need to do that].

> `Note -:` If you Use both pymongo and mongoenine together. Be careful, Because mongoengine have default validation function. So they check some validation before perform operations. But pymongo not have any validation, They just insert data and create collection [ If not exist ] and then insert data. So may be datatype conflict occur and problem like this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Seems like pymongo and mongoengine code can be mixed together except for validation purposes. I assume for queries, the code can be mixed.

Answer (score 1):

Your three questions:

'Can I use MongoEngine to define a document first, then use pymongo to insertMany documents into an empty collection? '

Yes.

'If yes, will pymongo's insertMany() do data validation based on the document definition set by mongoengine?'

No.

'Can pymongo and mongoengine code be mixed together in the same python script?'

Yes.

Mongoengine based on pymongo. If you do not need very complex function that mongoengine not had. I suggest you just use mongoengine to complete your work. This will save your time most of the time.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. One thing I don't quite understand from your answer. If pymongo and mongoengine code can be mixed together, why can't pymongo's insertMany() do data validation based on the document definition set by mongoengine?

Comment: Because mongengine do some extra work based on pymongo that pymongo not have. The validation in mongoengine should be used by itself. Pymongo can’t recognize these extra work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a novice when it comes to Python and Mongo. I believe you can validate each document with MongoEngine like so:

```
for my_obj in my_objs:
    my_obj.validate()
```

Then, bulk insert like so:

```
dicts = map(lambda my_obj: my_obj.to_mongo().to_dict(), my_objs)
collection.insert_many(dicts)
```

However, you can use MongoEngine to also bulk insert if you don't need to use PyMongo directly.